# Migration problems after update Django 1.8.1

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am having a real problem with python Django after updating from version 1.7.6 to version 1.8.1. The application itself is running fine, but when I try to do a migration on my remote database I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<my ip address>", user "test", database "postgres", SSL off
```

The fact that I cannot access postgres is good because that is the way it is configured, however in the settings I am not trying to access the 'postgres' database. This is what's in my settings file:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'test_db',
    'USER': 'test',
    'PASSWORD': '*******',
    'HOST': '<hostname>',,
    'PORT': '5432',
},
```

I cannot explain this, I am fairly new to Django and because it also looks like I cannot debug a "./manage.py migrate" I don't know where to search. If I try to run and debug my app without migrating it does get the right database from the settings file, but then I encounter database related errors of course because it hasn't migrated yet.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to check the `pg_hba.conf` file to see if it accepts connections from the IP that you are connecting from(Can even be `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @HiteshDharamdasani I have checked the pg_hba.conf. It allows my IP address to the database "test_db" but not to "postgres". So the error message makes sense, but what doesn't make sense to me is that it is trying to connect to "postgres" in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Django, you must upgrade to 1.8.2. See the second-to-last item in the [1.8.2 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8.2/#bugfixes).

In general, you should always upgrade to the latest minor version, i.e. the latest 1.8.x. A new minor version contains bugfixes and security patches, and is 100% backwards compatible, unless some incompatibility cannot be avoided to fix a data loss bug or a security issue.